# How to create an numpy array from several rows of DateFrame using 'values' atribute?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a DateFrame:

```
    TV  Radio   Newspaper   Sales
1   230.1   37.8    69.2    22.1
2   44.5    39.3    45.1    10.4
3   17.2    45.9    69.3    9.3
4   151.5   41.3    58.5    18.5
5   180.8   10.8    58.4    12.9
```

I need to create two NumPy arrays. One of them with `Sales` row content, and a second - with `TV`, `Radio` and `Newspaper` rows.

```
import numpy as np
first_arr = np.array(myDateFrame['Sales'].values) #It works
second_arr = np.array(myDateFrame['TV', 'Radio', 'Newspaper']) #It doesn't work
```

It gives the following error:

```
error: KeyError: ('TV', 'Radio', 'Newspaper')
```

Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> myDateFrame[['TV',  'Radio',  'Newspaper']].values
array([[ 230.1,   37.8,   69.2],
       [  44.5,   39.3,   45.1],
       [  17.2,   45.9,   69.3],
       [ 151.5,   41.3,   58.5],
       [ 180.8,   10.8,   58.4]])
```

There is no need to call `np.array()`. The attribute `values` is already a NumPy array.

Also note the double square brackets `[['TV',  'Radio',  'Newspaper']].` You need to supply multiple column names as a list, not as single arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [as_matrix()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) method for that:

> **DataFrame.as_matrix(columns=None)**
>
> Convert the frame to its Numpy-array representation.